# at command in ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, at-job

I am having simple ruby script which will send mail after certain time, this is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
system("at now + 1 day <<END
echo 'This is test message from xyz' | mail -s 'Test message' someone@example.com
END")
```

whenever I run this script, I get

> sh: END: not found

**Edit 1**

If I use on single line like

```
system("at now + 1 min echo 'This is test message from xyz' | mail -s 'Test message' someone@example.com")
```

it gives error :

> syntax error. Last token seen: e
>
> Garbled time

what am doing wrong in this ?

Comment: what does `END` command/template do?

Comment: @emaillenin I have used it for multiline command for `system`, If I am doing wrong than what would be the correct syntax for sending mail. ?

Comment: does it work if you do the same using a single line?

Comment: @emaillenin see my updated question

Comment: are you sure the same command works fine when you run from your Terminal?

Comment: `syntax error. Last token seen: e` This command does not work when run from the terminal. You get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `at` one-liner form can be like `echo 'COMMAND' | at WHEN`.

You can try this:

```
system("echo \"echo 'This is test message from xyz' | mail -s 'Test message' someone@example.com\" | at now + 1 day")
```

Comment: your suggestion will take me to `at>` command line which I don't want. I want this script should send the mail

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted. but could you please explain me bit. why have you used double `echo` ?

Comment: @arzyfex only the first `echo` matters, the second `echo` is just part of `COMMAND`.